# How to binding a JAVA server to a physical linux machine so that the code can only be run on this machine?

Tags: java

Right now, we want to

1. Fetch info like MAC address and some serial numbers and encoded them.
2. Inspect these info in realtime.

Is this safe enough to do so?
Is there any better meethod to implement this goal?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you have a threat model?

Comment: 1) If you have a guarantee that the machine is safe (i.e. 3rd party can't access its private files), then you don't need this much: RSA private key suffices for identification. 2) Otherwise, nothing will work. Whatever info you might request and whatever encryption you would use, if the machine is compromised, the info and encryption method are also compromised.

Comment: @PiRocks We provide privatized AI services which are deployed on their own servers. We do not want others to replace computer hardware to reduce/improve computing performance for economic consideration. Also, we do not want others to copy those code and run on other servers to provide services to thrid party.

Comment: As far as i understand what you want to achieve a lot of things are possible, actually. Basically just do the opposite of CI. When deploying for one and only one specific machine you can do things like hard coding class paths and resource paths instead of using paths relative from the project root or make assumptions about the machine the code is running on, like having important dependencies installed locally instead of using a project/dependency manager like Maven. This makes it more annoying and time consuming to get your code running if someone steals it. This is paranoia level 9001 btw.

Answer (score 0):

Going off your comments:

> We provide privatized AI services which are deployed on their own servers. We do not want others to replace computer hardware to reduce/improve computing performance for economic consideration. Also, we do not want others to copy those code and run on other servers to provide services to thrid party.

One could implement you service as some kind of server, therefore not allowing your clients any access to your code. This would obviously prevent them using your code on non-approved machines.

Alternatively you could copyright your code, with the terms of the copyright preventing use on non-approved machines. This is likely the most effective strategy.

As for this:

> Fetch info like MAC address and some serial numbers and encoded them.

I would expect users of an AI service to be highly technical. Therefore the above will be useless, since users can simply debug your code and determine what they need to patch to make your code work on non-approved machines.